# Блокировка HTTPS squid

Tags: https, прокси, squid

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема, необходимо с помощи прокси-сервера squid заблокировать такие сайты, как facebook, mail и тп. Большинство сайтов блокируется нормально, но эти работают с протоколом HTTPS и squid их не блокирует. Гугл запросы ничего толком не дали, возможно, сможете подсказать.